# iptable alternatives debian VPS

Tags: debian, reverse-proxy, nat, linux-networking

i am confused that i dont find any soloution...

i will configure an reverse proxy and that with iptables for my gameserver on debian:

```
Kernel: 2.6.32-openvz-042stab108.2-amd64


iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:27015
```

but i have an kernel on an VPS where NAT is not supported..

now i search for iptable alternatives where i can use NAT and others on my Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NAT functionality is (from my knowledge of kernel building) part of the kernel, so unless you are able to rebuild the kernel modules and/or can switch the kernel you most likely will be out of luck.

Comment: is there no other way without rebuilding or can u recommend an kernel ?

Comment: try to talk to your hoster about this.
Either they will add you another kernel with that support or tell you you cannot use this with that way.

Though i am not 100% sure there is no other option for your setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `socat` to forward that port to your game server:

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:27015,fork UDP4-SENDTO:x.x.x.x:27015
```

Note that x.x.x.x will see the requests coming from your reverse proxy. It won't see the original IP address. Also, no idea what performance implications this has.